# arima model の予測を描画したい

Tags: python

arimaでモデルを作り、未来予測を描画したいのですが、うまくいきません。

以下のコードを実行した場合、

```
arima_model_P = arima_model.predict('2023-01-01','2023-01-29')
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

plt.plot(df_400g_w, label="original")
plt.plot(arima_model_P, c="b", label="model-pred", alpha=0.7)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

下記のエラーが出ます。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 arima_model_P = arima_model.predict('2023-01-01','2023-01-29')
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
      4 plt.plot(df_400g_w, label="original")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\arima.py:777, in ARIMA.predict(self, n_periods, X, return_conf_int, alpha, **kwargs)
    775 check_is_fitted(self, 'arima_res_')
    776 if not isinstance(n_periods, int):
--> 777     raise TypeError("n_periods must be an int")
    779 # Temporary shim until we remove `exogenous` support completely
    780 X, _ = pm_compat.get_X(X, **kwargs)

TypeError: n_periods must be an int
```

また

```
arima_model_P = arima_model.predict('2023-01-01','2023-01-29')
```

の部分のpredict()をint型に変え、

```
arima_model_P = arima_model.predict(8)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

plt.plot(df_400g_w, label="original")
plt.plot(arima_model_P, c="b", label="model-pred", alpha=0.7)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

上記のように実行すると、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このような結果になります。

どうすれば、自然に結合することができまでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

描画されたグラフからの推定になりますが，`arima_model_P = arima_model.predict(8)` がインデックスを（元データから延長できず）数値「0, 1, ..., 7」で付加し，それを matplotlib が「1970-01-01, ...」と解釈して描画している思われます。
この推定が正しければ，下記のように `arima_model_P` のインデックスを日付型で再設定してから描画すれば所望の結果が得られます。

```
arima_model_P = arima_model.predict(8)

from datetime import date, timedelta
arima_model_P.index = [date(2023, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=4) * i
                       for i in range(8)]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.plot(df_400g_w, label="original")
plt.plot(arima_model_P, c="b", label="model-pred", alpha=0.7)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

ただし，ARIMA処理を始める前に元データのインデックスを日付型に変換して良いなら，その方が簡明です。その記述例も示します。

```
df_400g_w.index = pd.to_datetime(df_400g_w.index)
```

なお，変換がうまくいかない場合は [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) を参照して `format='...'` 等のオプションを検討ください。